# Complete form POST after redirect to sign in page and sign in

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have a form, on submit i check if the user is logged in, if not, I redirect to the signin page, once they sign in I want to complete the form POST that they were attempting. Any ideas on how to do this?

So far I have attempted storing the request path in a cookie and redirecting back using this path but on redirect it treats it as a GET rather than a POST which is not correct.

```
def store_location
  session[:return_to] = request.fullpath
end

def redirect_back_or(default)
  redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
  clear_return_to
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible workaround is as follows,

**Path 1 - user already logged in**

- submit form
- save the details

**Path 2 - User not logged in**

- submit form
- check user logged in (false in this
  case)
- redirect to the signup page
- have hidden fields in the signup page
  to store the earlier form details
- let user signup + add the previous
  for details after you create the user
  account

Note : these hidden fields (to store form1 data) should be optional as otherwise users should not be able to signup directly

HTH

sameera

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am sure this method would have worked. Here is what I ended up doing: I stored the original POST data in a cookie then redirected user to signup. If signup was successful I grabbed the data out of the cookie and ran the POST and deleted the cookie. Works great and was very simple to implement!

Comment: @istan, thats cool, I think its even better than my solution, and in my case users can see their data, (and might be able to change, if the user is techie..) but yours is more handy. :D

Comment: @istan, can you please show me your complete implementation? thanks